# Getting the error "Missing $ inserted" in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I try to write the following in latex:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{insert(element|text)} inserts the element or text passed at the start of the selection.
    \item \textbf{insert_after(element|text)} inserts the element or text passed at the end of the selection.
    \item \textbf{replace(element|text)} replaces the selection with the passed text/element.
    \item \textbf{delete()} deletes the selected text.
    \item \textbf{annotate(name,value)} annotates the selected text with the passed name and value-pair. This can either be a hidden meta-data about the selection, or can alter the visible appearance.
    \item \textbf{clear_annotation()} removes any annotation for this specific selection.
    \item \textbf{update_element(value)} performs an update of the element at the selection with the passed value.
\end{itemize}
```

For some reason, I get a bunch of errors. I think there is something with the use of the word "insert". I get errors like "Missing $ inserted", so it seems like the parses tries to fix some "errors" on my parts. Do I need to escape words like "insert", how do I do that?

Answer (score 391, accepted):

The "Missing $ inserted" is probably caused by the underscores and bars. These characters in  LaTeX have special meaning in math mode (which is delimited by `$` characters). Try escaping them; e.g. `update\_element` instead of `update_element`.

However, if you're trying to display code, a better solution would be to use the [`\verb` command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Verbatim_text), which will typeset the text in a monospaced font and will automatically handle underscores and bars correctly (no need to escape them with `\`).

Comment: I had this error because there was `$` symbol in one of the titles in my bibliography. Using `\$` helped.

Answer (score 53):

It's actually the underscores. Use `\_` instead, or include the *underscore* package.

Comment: texlive-latex-recommended has the underscore package. I had to also add the usepackage underscore to my sphinx.sty file

Comment: Using the 'underscore" package also solved an issue I encountered when trying to generate pdf out from a knitr document in RStudio by using the function "semTable" (before it resulted in the 'Missing $' error.

Answer (score 20):

I had this problem too. I solved it by removing the unnecessary blank line between *equation tags*. This gives the error:

```
\begin{equation}
P(\underline{\hat{X}} | \underline{Y}) = ...

\end{equation}
```

while this code compiles succesfully:

```
\begin{equation}
P(\underline{\hat{X}} | \underline{Y}) = ...
\end{equation}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. I was using a \label inside the equation and I had left a blank line after it.

Comment: I keep tripping over this one. I'd happily upvote this answer each time.

Answer (score 8):

also, I had this problem but the bib file wouldn't recompile. I removed the problem, which was an underscore in the note field, and compiled the tex file again, but kept getting the same errors. In the end I del'd the compiled bib file (.bbl I think) and it worked fine. I had to escape the _ using a backslash.

Comment: I to had an underscore in a note field. Thanks so much for suggesting this!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem - and I have read all these answers, but unfortunately none of them worked for me. Eventually I tried removing this line

```
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

and all errors disappeared.

Comment: and replacing it with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is not a bad idea

Answer (score 3):

My first guess is that LaTeX chokes on | outside a math environment.  **Missing $ inserted** is usually a symptom of something like that.

Comment: As @Will points out, LaTeX doesn't like _ .  Looks like a better explanation than mine too.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if you use special character greek letters like \alpha \beta and so on outside of math mode.
After i wrapped them in \(...\) the error was gone.

Comment: This worked for me. Any idea why this works and how to make it work without wrapping it?

Comment: it's an escape character.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I had this error with using `\rightarrow` outside math mode and after replacing it with `\(\rightarrow\)` the errors are gone.

Answer (score 1):

In my code, when I got the error, I checked the possible source, In a line, I had typed a beginning `\[` and an ending `\]` due to which the error of missing `$` appeared though I tried using `$` for both the brackets. Removing the brackets or using `$[$` instead of `$\[$` solved my problem. If you've something like that, try altering.

Answer (score 0):

I think it gives the error because of the underscore symbol.

Note : underscore symbol should not be written directly, you have to write like as `\_`.

So fix these kind special symbol errors.

Answer (score -1):

I had this symbol `_` in the head of one table and the code didn't run, so I had to delete.

Answer (score -1):

My case was similar to [Adrian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779615/16560397). It was an incorrectly written online bib source.

I had

```
 @online{some_pretty_website, 
    title={Pretty Website}, 
    url={https://www.prettywebsite.com/foo_bar.pdf}
 }
```

I had to **escape the "_" symbol** in the url

```
 @online{some_pretty_website, 
    title={Pretty Website}, 
    url={https://www.prettywebsite.com/foo\_bar.pdf}
 }
```